# Как прикрепить аудио с помощью VK API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, аудио

Мне необходимо прикрепить аудио от имени сообщества. Как это сделать с помощью VK API?

Comment: А документацию почитать пробовали?) https://vk.com/dev/messages.send

Comment: @inventor, Вопрос конечно не полный, из него не понятно на каком этапе и что именно не работает, но у меня, например, vkaudio.get тоже с ошибкой падает. Не возвращает список треков пользователя (хотя может развидеть список треков сообщества)

Comment: @Amunrah ну так покажите свою ошибку, чтобы мы не гадали на кофейной гуще